# How can i join two tables(documents) and get unmatched data using mongoose(express,nodejs)?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, join, express, mongoose

i have two tables(documents) offers and applied offers i need to combine and get unmatched data from offers table.
for example i have stored some object in database. i am using meanjs for this i dono where can i write routes for join both tables(documents) and where can i write function for join pls some one help me to get this done

```
$scope.offers = [{

        id: "1",
        storeid: "986745",
        couponname: "healthy breakfast offer",
        offermessage: "50% offer for break fast",
        noofcoupon: "10"
    }, {
         id: "2",
        storeid: "886745",
        couponname: "get 50% lunch",
        offermessage: "50% offer for Lunch",
        noofcoupon: "10"
    }, {
         id: "3",
        storeid: "690745",
        couponname: "dinner damaka",
        offermessage: "50% offer for dinner",
        noofcoupon: "10"
    },
    {
         id: "4",
         storeid: "550745",
        couponname: "supper festiwal",
        offermessage: "80% offer for supper",
        noofcoupon: "10"
    },

    {
         id: "5",
         storeid: "690733",
        couponname: "eve damaka snaks",
        offermessage: "20% offer for snaks",
        noofcoupon: "10",
    }

    ]
```

and applied offers table(documents) i have stored data like this

```
$scope.appliedoffers = [{

       id: "1",
        storeid: "986745",
        couponname: "healthy breakfast offer",
        offermessage: "50% offer for break fast",
        noofcoupon: "10",
    }, {
         id: "2",
         storeid: "690733",
        couponname: "eve damaka snaks",
        offermessage: "20% offer for snaks",
        noofcoupon: "10"
    }

    ]
```

for given example if we put join and get unmatched data it should display only 3 here storeid is there in two tables

```
{
         id: "2",
        storeid: "886745",
        couponname: "get 50% lunch",
        offermessage: "50% offer for Lunch",
        noofcoupon: "10"
    }, {
         id: "3",
        storeid: "690745",
        couponname: "dinner damaka",
        offermessage: "50% offer for dinner",
        noofcoupon: "10"
    },
    {
         id: "4",
         storeid: "550745",
        couponname: "supper festiwal",
        offermessage: "80% offer for supper",
        noofcoupon: "10"
    },
```

i have added my routes and controller i don't know how to grab unmatched data .i have added routes and controller how can i change controller to get unmatched data

offer routes

```
'use strict';

    module.exports = function(app) {
        var users = require('../../app/controllers/users.server.controller');
        var offers = require('../../app/controllers/offers.server.controller');

        // Offers Routes
        app.route('/offers')
            .get(offers.list)
            .post(users.requiresLogin, offers.create);

        app.route('/offers/:offerId')
            .get(offers.read)
            .put(users.requiresLogin, offers.hasAuthorization, offers.update)
            .delete(users.requiresLogin, offers.hasAuthorization, offers.delete);

        // Finish by binding the Offer middleware
        app.param('offerId', offers.offerByID);
    };
```

offer controller:for get function

```
/**
 * Offer middleware
 */
exports.offerByID = function(req, res, next, id) { 
    Offer.findById(id).populate('user', 'displayName').exec(function(err, offer) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        if (! offer) return next(new Error('Failed to load Offer ' + id));
        req.offer = offer ;
        next();
    });
};
```

applied offer routes:

'

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function(app) {
    var users = require('../../app/controllers/users.server.controller');
    var appliedoffers = require('../../app/controllers/appliedoffers.server.controller');

    // Appliedoffers Routes
    app.route('/appliedoffers')
        .get(appliedoffers.list)
        .post(users.requiresLogin, appliedoffers.create);

    app.route('/appliedoffers/:appliedofferId')
        .get(appliedoffers.read)
        .put(users.requiresLogin, appliedoffers.hasAuthorization, appliedoffers.update)
        .delete(users.requiresLogin, appliedoffers.hasAuthorization, appliedoffers.delete);

    // Finish by binding the Appliedoffer middleware
    app.param('appliedofferId', appliedoffers.appliedofferByID);
};
```

applied offer controller:

/**
 * Appliedoffer middleware
 */

```
exports.appliedofferByID = function(req, res, next, id) { 
    Appliedoffer.findById(id).populate('user', 'displayName').exec(function(err, appliedoffer) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        if (! appliedoffer) return next(new Error('Failed to load Appliedoffer ' + id));
        req.appliedoffer = appliedoffer ;
        next();
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do this at the database side and be much more efficient about it.

Since the latest release of MongoDB (3.2) it's possible to do a $lookUp which is effectively a left-outer join.

Download the latest version of mongodb from mongodb.org and check out the $lookUp documentation for performing the join across collections here:

https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/

Comment: According to the mongolab support page, they currently only run mongodb 3.0: http://docs.mongolab.com/ops/#available-versions You may have to wait a little for 3.2.

Comment: how can i solve my issue .is there any idea instead of that